# nginx: use geo module with a domain instead of IP

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I use nginx to host wordpress. Naturally I'm looking to secure the wp-admin and wp-login.php pages so they are only accessible to pre-authorized servers.

In my sites-available I'm defining the allowed IP(s). And later using variable $wpadmin to allow / disallow wp-admin page:

```
geo $wpadmin {
    default 0;
    1.2.3.4 1;
}
```

Now my problem is that IP "1.2.3.4" is dynamic and I have to update the config each time it changes. I'd like to use a domain instead e.g. dynamic dns "example.no-ip.com"

Any help how to resolve a hostname and use the result is appreciated.

I could do a little script that checks my dns every x minutes and if needed overwrite the config file with the new IP and reloads nginx config. However this will be not elegant and needs attention to script ownership / permissions to be secure.

Comment: That would be a completely separate functionality in nginx, and would require additional module to implement. Your easiest choice is to implement it via the script.

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible with [`rdns`](https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns) module.

It can do a reverse DNS lookup for the remote IP, and subsequently you can allow/deny based on incoming hostname.

Comment: how do i install this rdns module